# com.mongodb cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to work with mongoDB and Java. I can't make Java get the resources to use MongoDB.

I have downloaded the MongoDB Java Drivers as well as the BSONS files and added both jars into the build path. Tried with the Driver 3.0.4 and the 3.3.0 versions of the MongoDB Java Driver but none works, and i still get the dreaded:

```
The import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be resolved
```

That goes for every import from the com.mongodb package.

I have checked the compatibility  [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/)  and downloaded the drivers from  [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/).

I am only trying to make simple test so connecting to a Database on localhost will suffice.

The only thing I can think of is the dependencies on Maven? I don't really understand or know what that it is but every guide, tutorial or any source material I have looked does not mention it so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Can you add some code you are using to establish the connection? Also have you installed a mongoDB server on you local machine?

Comment: add jars to build path , ant try to clean and re build

Comment: So far there is no code, i can't even get the imports to work, so i haven't done anything. The only piece of code is the actual import.

As said on the original post, jars were added to the build already. A Clean re build also did not work.

Comment: If you have the jar, it's a build path issue. How do you build your projetc, with an IDE? which IDE?. Are you using some build tools like Maven or Ant or Gradle or are you just using plain old IDE project? Without more details we can't help you

Comment: I have managed to find the issue. I was just being very stupid. It was not working because i downloaded the javadoc jar instead of the pure driver jar.  Once i created a Maven Project and compared the dependencies it became clear.

I apologize for bad question.